# IF-ELSE statements execution order

Tags: sql-server

I have very strange situation: I created a small script to alter (make it identity and primary key) one column in a table.
It looks like ALTER operators to make a column a primary executes always and first. I know it sounds crazy, but this is what I see.
My source column (`SampleCode`) EXISTS and it is INT and allow null.
The script:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'SampleCode' AND Object_ID = Object_ID('SAMPLE'))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SAMPLE.SampleCode is present'
    END
ELSE
    -- If SAMPLE.SampleCode not exists
    BEGIN
        PRINT '  Column SAMPLE.SampleCode not exists'
        ALTER TABLE SAMPLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SAMPLE PRIMARY KEY (SampleCode)
    END
```

The first section (`PRINT 'SAMPLE.SampleCode is present'`) should be executed.
But if the `ALTER TABLE` operator is uncommented (the column IS present this ELSE branch should not executed) I got the error:

> Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'SAMPLE'.

If I comment out the ALTER TABLE SAMPLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SAMPLE PRIMARY KEY (SampleCode) line, then everything works as expected (IF branch):
**SAMPLE.SampleCode is present**

I have not faced with this behavior before and will be very thankful for any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a parse-time issue, not a runtime issue - your ALTER TABLE is parsed and evaluated independently of your IF logic (the parser ignores it). One easy fix is to do `EXEC sys.sp_executesql(N'ALTER TABLE ...');`, which is ignored by parse time.